# Going from one corner to another, using D and R. Is there a nicer way?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have an $m \times n $ grid and I want to get from the top left corner to the bottom right corner, but only being allowed to go down and right.

If we consider a sequence of $m$ R's and $n$ D's, there is a bijection between the permutations of this sequence and the number of routes. In other words, by counting the number of permutations, we count the number of routes as the sets have equal cardinality.

The number of routes will then just be $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ but this is also equal to $\binom{m+n}{n}$ or $\binom{m+n}{m}$.

My question is, due to the very simple nature of the answer, is there a very simple way of viewing the scenario such that we have the result immediately?

Comment: Normally $m$ stands for the number of rows. If so then I would expect $m$ D's (down) and $n$  R's (right).

Answer (score 3):

There are $m+n$ steps "at your disposal", and exactly $m$ of these steps must be selected as the steps going down.

That immediately makes $\binom{m+n}{m}$ "appear".

I am not sure yet whether this answers your question.